# Set Firebase Storage Image URL into src of img tag

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-storage

This is the html img tag

```
<img [src]=getImage(admin.id) alt="Driver Icon" style="width: 180px;>
```

Here is the **getImage()** function

```
  getImage(id: string){
    let retURL: string
    const userStorageRef = firebase.storage().ref('adminImages').child(id);
    userStorageRef.getDownloadURL().then(function onSuccess(url) {
      retURL = url
    })  
    .catch(function onError(err) {
      retURL = "../../../../assets/adminavatar.png"
      console.log("Image Not Found-",err);
    })
    return retURL
  }
```

Any error is not shown in the console or in the node terminal. Only thing happening is the crashing App.
When returning URL by hardcoding like below

```
  getImage(id: string){
    let retURL: string = "../../../../assets/adminavatar.png"
    return retURL
  }
```

it will work properly. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: try creating a demo on stackblitz ? There must be some errors in console or terminal.

Comment: Do you take into account the fact that the `getDownloadURL()` method is asynchronous? I'm not really verse in angular but your crash may come from the fact that `getImage(admin.id)` in the `img` tag is not holding the image url value until the promise returned by the `getDownloadURL()` is resolved. You should try setting the `src` attribute of the `img` tag from within the `then()` method.